# C - Nice way to terminate

Tags: c, client-server, parent-child, infinite-loop, exit

Is there a nice way out of an infinite loop? (I tried catching a SIGINT, but it won't let me clean up before exiting)

I'm doing a client-server. 
Each time a client connects, the server forks and designates a child to the client (this child will redirect stdin and stdout to a fd of a fifo or socket and then execl)
In the server I am currently listening for clients in an infinite loop

```
for(;;)
{
    listen_client();
    create_child();
}
```

(more or less)
The application works fine (each client can communicate perfectly with it's designated child-server).
The problem comes on server-closure.

I was wondering if there was a nice way for the server to close (I'm not used on using endless loops, not sure if it's the right way and not sure if there is a nice way out).

I tried a sig_handler (sigaction), but I can't seem to make it work (ideally, I would close all fd, kill all childs and delete all fifos before exiting).

**EDIT**

with a global variable that keeps track of childs and a modification in sig_handler() it seems to be working, still not sure it's a nice way

(code in sig handler)

```
while(childs > 0)
{
    pid = wait(NULL);
    //cleanup mess of child
    childs--
}
```

my doubts are:
are children always dying automatically? or should I send a kill or something (in which case I'd guess I would need to keep track of every pid).
is there a risk of creating zombies?
is there a risk of entering an endless loop? (I never decrease "childs" other than here, I'm not sure if wait also counts the children dead long ago).

I know this "works", but I'd rather learn to do it the "right" way (if there is such thing)

Comment: `break;` where is the problem?

Comment: the problem is how I determine where to break.
I WANT the loop to be "infinite" (continue to listen for clients as long as it runs), what I want is for it to die clean

Comment: Modify the infinite loop to `while (termsig_received == 0) { ... }`, and have the signal handler set the variable declared as `static volatile sig_atomic_t termsig_received = 0;` to 1, and then after the loop, clean-up to your hearts content.  You can do more in a signal handler on Linux than you can according to standard C, but it's still generally best to avoid doing much in a signal handler, and setting a flag and testing that is a good way to do it.  You might need to modify the `listen_client()` code to return a value such as 0 if a child is to be created and -1 if it was interrupted.

Comment: is this going to work on a SIGINT?
if I follow correctly, the sig would only change the variable, how exactly would it affect the process (where does the process resume?)
wouldn't it be still blocked by the listen_client()?
for example, if listen_client() is waiting for a client to open a fifo (or write, or anything that would produce a block), and the sigaction takes place, wouldn't it continue to be blocked when it returns?

Comment: the code could use the 'atexit()' function to the parameter to atexit is a function name.  And that function does all the cleanup.

Comment: I tried, but I don't think atexit() handles SIGINT. I think it works only on normal exits (which I am unable to produce due to the infinite loop)

Answer (score 0):

You could disable async signal generation, create a signalfd(2) and poll(2) on that. That way you can handle all signals correctly and keep a linear program flow including correct cleanup. IMO this is a very convenient solution.